# Adding several bounties

Tags: support, bounties

Isn't it possible to add several bounties (to different questions)? I added a bounty to a question yesterday, and for reason, I can't add a bounty to another today...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can only have one active bounty per user as well as only one per question.

Basically any question can only have one active bounty at any one tim and a user can only have one active bounty at any one time.

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

> There can only be 1 active bounty per question and per user at any given time.

There are some further details on the improvements made to the Bounty system on [this blog post.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/)

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wqnted to know. I saw this in the FAQ, but it's a bit misleading...