# Can bounties be awarded multiple times by the same person on the same question?

Tags: support, bounties

Is there any restriction to prevent multiple bounties ( not simultaneously) being awarded to different answers on the same question ?

i.e., on a question [I had asked](https://superuser.com/q/240794/4377) -  I want to set multiple bounties since I've received 2 awesome answers. Can I set award a bounty on answer A first, and then set the bounty and award it to answer B ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Adding several bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72121/adding-several-bounties) says only one active at a time, but @YiJiang says you can award multiple on the same question, looking for a MSO answer to that regard.

And he provides proof in the chatroom with this image: [image: an image that belongs to YiJiang]

Comment: Though nowadays the bounty amount [must double for each subsequent bounty offered by the same person on the same question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639).

Comment: @Arjan Until you hit the limit.  You can offer infinite 500 point bounties...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can.

Here is an example where I awarded five bounties to four different answers on the same question:

[Fast method to copy memory with translation - ARGB to BGR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804101/fast-method-to-copy-memory-with-translation-argb-to-bgr)

I gave two bounties to the same answer, and the other three bounties to different answers.

Answer (score 2):

One user **can** start multiple bounties on the same question.  If you find yourself being unable to do so, it means that either

1. There already is an *active bounty on this question* or
2. *You already have 3 other active bounties* that you started (that's maximum)