# Setting a bounty on someone else's question to acknowledge a great answer

Tags: discussion, bounties, etiquette

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868223/jquery-find-all-comma-in-an-ul-and-erase-them-replace-with/5868390#5868390) is really good, and I really like to give more than the meager +1 that I can.

Since it's not my question, I can't give +15 by accepting and even if I'll ask the OP to accept it instead of my answer, I don't think it's enough.

So my question is: is it acceptable to start a +50 bounty and then reward that answer as soon as possible? Will it indeed make people understand it's a good answer?

Opinions are welcome!

**Edit:**
OK, bounty has been set. Added comment to the OP question as well. :)

Comment: My question on the same point - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78187/can-bounties-be-awarded-multiple-times-by-the-same-person-on-the-same-question

Comment: +1 because you accept somebody elses answer is better than yours. This is the way SE should work. Teach and learn. And a bounty is a perfect way to show this. (As a side note: I like the avatar, looks like a nice kid).

Comment: @Gamecat thanks, glad to see positive responses and yes indeed my girl is the nicest in the world! :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can, and whether or not the community will see that it's a good answer, that person will be rewarded for their good answer.  It does show the awarded bounty next to the answer, so that would indicate that it's at least done something worthy of reward.

Answer (score 3):

It is even supposed approach fully supported by the Stack Exchange ecosystem. Check Investor and Alturist badges. These bounties are also supposed to be used as *thanks that was a great answer*. You can start a bounty on any question if these rules (copied from [Stack Oveflow FAQs](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)) are satisfied:

- Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.
- Users must have at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty.
- There can only be 1 active bounty per question and per user at any given time.
- Once initiated, the bounty period lasts 7 days.
- After starting a bounty, you must wait 1 day before awarding it.
- If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, certainly. (At least I hope so, because I've done it before).

Since you can't award the bounty immediately, you should add a comment on the question explaining what the bounty is intended for. Otherwise it's unfair to people who might think you're not satisfied with any of the existing answers and do unnecessary work to write a new answer.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of the comment - good point. :)